# Learning React Native, asking about function vs class

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im learning react native and I have a question, im watching course from 2018 where teacher use Export default class, and in new tutorials i see that ppl use export default function, soo should i use class or  function in my apps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Const vs Class Functions is React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762163/const-vs-class-functions-is-react-native)

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965/when-to-use-es6-class-based-react-components-vs-functional-es6-react-components

Comment: you can use the class system or the newer Hooks approach in React / react native - depends on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

use accordingly, but hooks are easy way to implement in any project. 
The benefit that I could see is in Redux:-

It eliminates the use of connect function in class that is a higher order component

Using Class:=

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        test: test(state),
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    test: () => dispatch(test),
  });
```

Using Hooks:=

```
const test = `useSelector`(state => state.test); //similar to mapStateToProps 

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux;
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(test); //similar to mapDispatchToProps
```

Please comment if anyone find other advantages too.